# Test net ether disappear

Tags: ether, testnets

I'm having a private test network. I mined more than 20k ether and equally distributed to all my account. Today when I opened geth and found all the ethers except in first account disappeared. Can any know what causes this? and how to recover ether. Thank you.

Comment: Did you check all your transactions were mined successfully ?

Comment: yes after transaction I make sure all the accounts have ether